# How do I mirror a database from remote Linux into Windows localhost?

Tags: 7, database, migrations

I would like to mirror Linux *dev.example.com* into Windows *dev.example.com.local* properly to be able to do development locally.

1. I have already set up *xampp* and *hosts* (dev.example.com.local)
2. I have created localhost mysql database instance (dev).
3. I have set up Drupal 7 settings.php on local.
4. I can export remote db into sql.zip file and I can import it into local db

The key question I have now is 
**how to properly handle mysql export and import to make sure both local and remote mysql instances are in sync?**

I bet Step 4 is not enough here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 4 is enough, they both will be in sync until you change data on one or the other instance.

As a bonus tip, you can ease this procedure by using `drush` to sync your environnements, via the use of [drush aliases](https://network.acquia.com/documentation/cloud/about/drush-aliases).

More details on this [here](https://network.acquia.com/documentation/cloud/about/drush-aliases).

Good-luck friend, happy coding.

Comment: I like answers of `@greg-anderson` and `@betaride` too but this one in my opinion is the most relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You need only add an important step 5 to the above list:

1. drush clear-cache all

Unfortunately, drush sql-sync is not currently supported on Windows.  Patches welcome!

Comment: thank you , as you noticed I am looking for a Windows compatible solution here.

Answer (score 1):

A very hand module for this is [backup and migrate](http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate). It creates or intalls a complete backup of your db with one mouse click.